# What aviation regulations govern the use of drones in Ireland?

Tags: regulations, ireland

I am thinking about starting to fly drones in Ireland.  What are the rules that are going to apply, and where can I find the latest information about the laws that govern the hobby in Ireland.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of drones in Ireland is covered by the regulations in the [Small Unmanned Aircraft (Drones) and Rockets Order, 2015](https://www.iaa.ie/publications/docs/default-source/publications/legislation/statutory-instruments-(orders)/small-unmanned-aircraft-(drones)-and-rockets-order-s-i-563-of-2015) (SI 563 of 2015). There are also Aeronautical Notices that apply to the use of drones only.  These notices can be checked on the [website of the Irish Aviation Authority](https://www.iaa.ie/publications?taxonomy=categories&propertyName=category&taxon=%2Fpublication-categories%2Faeronautical-notices).

Broadly, the regulations require that any drone flown in Ireland may not be operated:

- if it will be a hazard to another aircraft in flight
- over an assembly of 12 persons or more
- farther than 300m from the person operating the drone
- within 30m of any person, vessel or structure not under the control of the person operating the drone
- within 5km of an aerodrome
- in a "*negligent or reckless manner*" so as to "*endanger life or property of others*"
- more than 400ft (120m) above ground level
- over urban areas
- in civil or military-controlled airspace
- in restricted areas (e.g. military installations, prisons, etc.)
- unless the person operating the drone has permission from the landowner for take-off and landing.

---

Note that the situation in Ireland will change later this year (2020), when the new European Regulations on the rules and procedures for the operation of drones (or "*Unmanned Aircraft Systems (UAS)*”) come into force.

The situation is explained in [Aeronatical Notice U.06](https://www.iaa.ie/docs/default-source/publications/aeronautical-notices/u---unmanned-aircraft/the-pending-introduction-of-(eu)-regulations-in-the-area-of-unmanned-aircraft-systems-(uas)-in-ireland.pdf?sfvrsn=8d231ef3_4), with the catchy title: *The pending introduction of (EU) Regulations in the area of Unmanned Aircraft Systems (UAS) in Ireland*, available to read or download from the website of the Irish Aviation Authority.

---

The most up-to-date information can always be obtained from the [website of the Irish Aviation Authority](https://www.iaa.ie/).